# Outputting recent comments in a different part of the node

Tags: comments

I have created a custom node, and at the bottom of this node I would like to show the latest three comments made on that node. I have added the code below to my template.php, and then loop through the array to get the data in my node:

```
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1))) 
{
    $result = db_query_range('SELECT c.cid, c.nid, c.subject, c.name
    FROM {comment} c WHERE c.nid = :cid ORDER BY c.cid DESC', 0, 3, array(':cid' => arg(1)));

    $i = 0;     
    foreach ($result as $record) {
        $variables['NewComments']['NewSubject'][$i] = $record -> subject;
        $variables['NewComments']['NewName'][$i] = $record -> name;
        $i++;
    }
}

else {
    $variables['errorCheck'] = t('nope fail');
}
```

However, I am having trouble outputting this into the node.tpl. Is there an easy way to do this, or should I try something else to tackle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using views.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you can either add this view as a block or you can use http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7 in node.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well. I'm going from D6 to D7 and the views module seems to have changed... Is there a way to make it show just comments subjects without them becoming links?